# why loss changes value after I add additional inference with reuse = True

Tags: tensorflow

In tensorflow example cifar10, the loss value changes after I add one more inference with reuse = True to the graph.

Originally:

```
2016-11-13 06:08:04.936044: step 0, loss = 4.68 (6.5 examples/sec;
19.787 sec/batch)
```

After my change:

```
2016-11-13 06:00:50.400917: step 0, loss = 7.05 (6.4 examples/sec; 20.109 sec/batch)
```

I don't understand why. All the changes I made are as following,

1) In `cifar10_train.py`, I added a line,

```
logits = cifar10.inference(images, reuse = False)
logits2 = cifar10.inference(images, reuse=True)
```

2) In `cifar10.py`, I added reuse to `inference()`

```
def inference(images, reuse):
  with tf.variable_scope('conv1', reuse) as scope:
......
```

Then I found the loss value is quite different.

Originally:

```
2016-11-13 06:08:04.936044: step 0, loss = 4.68 (6.5 examples/sec; 19.787 sec/batch)
```

After my change:

```
2016-11-13 06:00:50.400917: step 0, loss = 7.05 (6.4 examples/sec; 20.109 sec/batch)
```

Why is this?

Comment: Have you tried to run the code multiple times? Does this happen every time? Many of the training algorithms in deep learning are stochastic.

Comment: Do you use tensorflow r0.11? If you really changed only that line, it _really_ shouldn't change anything, as the second parameter of the [tf.variable_scope](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#variable_scope) is `default_name` (to change reuse you would do `tf.variable_scope('conv1', reuse=reuse)`)

Comment: The problem can be always reproduced.

Comment: I used 0.9.0rc0

Answer (score 0):

parameter reuse is True means logits and logits2 use the same model to get their output, if reuse is False, logits and logits2 come from different model
for more information to understand what I said, you can watch this: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variable_scope